# Headless server has stuck "del" key, making it unmanageable. How can I disable keyboard via VBS?

Tags: scripting, keyboard, vbscript, headless

I have a headless Windows 2008 R2 box that seems to have a keyboard plugged in and something is pressing on the delete key.

I'm using GotoMypc to access the box and am unable to click on device manager, or use the command line (backspace is quite dastardly).

I just realised I can transfer a file (via GotoMyPC) and double click it (my test files have not been deleted).  I think I can use this functionality to regain some control of my box... possible using VBS or something.  What do you think?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try downloading [devcon.exe](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;Q311272) and running

```
devcon find *
```

to identify the hardware ID and then

```
devcon disable <HardwareID>
```

to disable it.  For example:

```
P:\>devcon find * | find /i "keyboard"
HID\VID_413C&PID_2105\6&237B9D6D&0&0000                     : HID Keyboard Device
ROOT\RDP_KBD\0000                                           : Terminal Server Keyboard Driver

P:\>devcon disable HID\VID_413C&PID_2105\6&237B9D6D&0&0000
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you call whoever is responsible and have someone take the keyboard and hit him on his head HARD.

Broken hardware. Fix that first. If some iddiot put in a broken keyboard he can gladly pay all costs associated with it.

Comment: I would... but no-one is on site for at least a day.